# Why are convergence in probability and convergence of means equivalent in this case?

Tags: probability-theory

In [A Probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition by Luc Devroye. László Györfi. Gábor Lugosi](http://www.szit.bme.hu/~gyorfi/pbook.pdf),

> DEFINITION 6.1. A classification rule is consistent for a certain distribution of $(X, Y)$ if
>   $$
> E L_n = P(g_n(X,D_n) \neq Y) \to L^*
> $$
>   as $n \to \infty$.
>
> REMARK. Consistency is defined as the convergence of the expected value of $L_n$ to
>   $L^*$. Since $L_n$ is a random variable bounded between $L^*$ and $1$, this convergence is equivalent to the convergence of $L_n$ to $L^*$ in probability, which means that for every $\epsilon > 0$
>   $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} P(L_n- L^*>\epsilon)=0.
> $$

Here $L^*$ is a constant, not a random variable.
I was wondering why when $L_n$ is bounded between $L^*$ and $1$, convergence of $EL_n$ to $L^*$ is equivalent to convergence of $L^n$ to $L^*$ in probability.

If $L^*$ were a random variable, will it still be true that when $L_n$ is bounded between $L^*$ and $1$, convergence of $EL_n$ to $L^*$ is equivalent to convergence of $L^n$ to $L^*$ in probability?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first question can be rephrased as follows:

> Assume that $0\leqslant X_n\leqslant c$ almost surely for every $n$, for some finite $c$, and that $X_n\to0$ in probability, then $\mathbb E(X_n)\to0$.

For a proof, note that $X_n\leqslant \varepsilon+c\mathbf 1_{X_n\geqslant \varepsilon}$ hence $\mathbb E(X_n)\leqslant\varepsilon+c\mathbb P(X_n\geqslant\varepsilon)$, for every fixed $\varepsilon\gt0$. Let $n\to\infty$. Then $\mathbb P(X_n\geqslant\varepsilon)\to0$ by hypothesis, hence $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb E(X_n)\leqslant\varepsilon$. This holds for every $\varepsilon\gt0$ hence $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb E(X_n)=0$.

The case mentioned at the end of the post is absurd since the real numbers $\mathbb E(L_n)$ can only converge to a real number, not to a (nondegenerate) random variable.

Comment: Thank you! How does $E(X_n) \to 0$ imply $X_n \to 0$ in probability?

Comment: Convergence in $L^1$ **always** implies convergence in probability.